# Invalid Operation Exception passing to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am trying, to no avail to display a dropdown list of all units a user doesnt already have. So i have List A with all Units and List B with all Units the user has.  What i want is List C which is basically List A with List B removed from it.  I have so far managed to filter out the data but i cant seem to display it in my View.  All i get is a blank dropdown list.  Can anyone see where im going wrong??

```
public ActionResult AddUnit(String usrCode)
    {
        var units = unitsClient.GetAllunits();
        var allunitsCode = (from s in units select s.unitCode).ToList();
        var thisUnitCode = (from s in db.Units
                                   where s.UsrCode == usrCode
                                   select s.UnitCode).ToList(); 
        var notGot = allunitsCode.Except(thisUnitCode);
        List<unitsummaryDTO> list = UnitList(units, notGot);
        ViewBag.unitCode = new SelectList(list, "unitCode", "unitTitle");
        var model = new UserUnit { UsrCode = usrCode };
        return View("AddUnit", model);
    }

private List<unitsummaryDTO> UnitList(unitsService.unitsDTO[] units, IEnumerable<string> notGot)
    {
        var allunits = unitsClient.GetAllunits();
        var allunitsCode = (from s in allunits select s.unitCode).ToList();
        IEnumerable<String> list1 = allunitsCode;
        IEnumerable<String> list2 = notGot;
        var listFinal = list1.Union(list2).toList;

        return listFinal.Select(x => new unitsummaryDTO(){unitCode = x}).ToList();
    }
```

This is my View model.  But all i get is a blank drop down?? Can anyone help me out.

```
@model Projv1.UserUnit
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.unitCode)
@Html.DropDownList("UnitCode")
```

Comment: You're assigning `unitCode` to the ViewBag, not the Model.

Comment: I want the unitCode to be in the ViewBag dont i? Im not sure how i would change it to be passed to Model?

Comment: Maybe, but then your view uses `unitcode` from the model.

Comment: Show the details of your error.

Comment: There is no error, it compiles and runs fine.  Its just that when i view the page the dropdown is blank.  On debug the model variable is also saying null for unitCode and unitTitle???

Answer (score 0):

It would be blank because `@Html.DropDownList("UnitCode")` doesn't have a source. If you look at [MSDN for Html.DropDownList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.dropdownlist%28v=vs.111%29.aspx), the one your most likely trying to use is `DropDownList(String, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)`.

Your putting your select list into the `ViewBag` as `unitCode` so try:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Unit Code", ViewBag.unitCode);
```

A much easier way of handling this is to extend `UserUnit` as a ViewModel (or create something) to have the items needed by the `SelectList` on it and let MVC do the heavy lifting in the binding.

```
public class UserUnit 
{
   // ... other properties

   IEnumerable<unitsummaryDTO> UnitCodes { get; set; }

   public string MyUnitCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.MyUnitCode, 
                         new SelectList(Model.UnitCodes, "unitCode", "unitTitle"))
```

Comment: Could i use this method and also maintain my excluded UnitCodes ??

Comment: You can populate `UnitCodes` with whatever you need to. It's the View's job to display what its given, so you can give it anything :-)